# DateTimePicker to have dates and times booked from Database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, razor

I am currently developing an appointments app in C# asp.net.

The app involves someone putting in for an appointment. Currently, I do a check when the form is submitted if the admin is not available but I would like to do it dynamically.

I am using a Javascript/jQuery DateTimePicker and ideally I would like to do the following:

- The dates that no appointments are available should be grayed out
- the times that are not available or when an admin are booked, should be in red

I know I need an Ajax call to carry this out but I'm at a total loss.

Here's my DateTimePicker:

```
<script>
$('#DateOfAppointment').datetimepicker({
    format: 'd/m/Y H:i',
    minDate: 0,
    inline: true,
    allowTimes: ['9:00', '9:30', '11:30', '12:00', '12:30', '14:00', '14:30', '15:00', '15:30', '16:00', '16:30', '17:00']
});
```

If anyone wants the CSS file or the script, I can make it available.

**EDIT** I'll include my controller method and my updated datetimepicker:

```
public JsonResult UnAvailableSlots()
    {
        var events = (from a in db.Appointments
                      select a).ToList();

        return new JsonResult { Data = events, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }

    @section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>

}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var events = [];
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Appointments/UnAvailableSlots",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                    events.push({
                        details: v.DetailsOfAppointment,
                        date: moment(v.DateOfAppointment),
                        room: v.RoomType,
                        confirmed: v.Confirmed,
                        colour: v.ThemeColour,
                        church: v.Church.Name,
                        parishAdminName: v.Admins.AdministratorName,
                        parishAdminUser: v.Admins.AdminUsername,
                        parishAdminId: v.Admins.AdministratorId,
                        fee: v.Fee,
                        id: v.AppointmentId
                    });

                })
                GenerateCalender(events);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("failed");
                console.log(error);
            }
        })

        function GenerateCalender(events) {
            $('#DateOfAppointment').datetimepicker({
                format: 'd/m/Y H:i',
                minDate: 0,
                inline: true,
                disabledDates: [events.date],
                allowTimes: ['9:00', '9:30', '11:30', '12:00', '12:30', '14:00', '14:30', '15:00', '15:30', '16:00', '16:30', '17:00']
            });
        }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Which `datetimepicker` are you using.?

Comment: @weBBer using this http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Answer (score 0):

Too bad that this plugin does not support ajax and callbacks for allow date and times.

you'd have to set: https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#allowDates

```
allowDates:['not','full','dates']
```

When a date is chosen you can overwrite allowTimes with:

```
$('#input').datetimepicker('setOptions', {allowTime:['times']});
```

like this:

```
onSelectDate:function(date,$i){
  // your ajax call here with callback method updating datepicker
  api.availableHoursOnDay(date,function(hoursOpen){
         $('#input').datetimepicker('setOptions', {allowTime:hoursOpen});
  })
  alert(ct.dateFormat('d/m/Y'))
}
```

It might be a bit hacky. but the only other way would to be:

- Download the source code and change it to your needs
- Create your own plugin/datepicker.